# API for Android NFC phone with ACR122 NFC reader

Tags: android, api, nfc

I was wondering if there is an API or sample source code that will allow me to:

-Send a string from my NFC phone (Nexus S 4G)
-Receive the string on my Android tablet (which is connected to a ACR122 Reader via USB)

So in other words, a user can tap their Nexus S phone on the ACR122 NFC reader and the string (or some data) will be sent from the phone to Android tablet (which is connected to the ACR122 reader)

There is a company called Adelya Labs that has figured out how to communicate between an NFC phone and a tablet connected to an NFC reader, but I'm not sure what API they used or sample source code. Here's a YouTube video demonstrating what I want to do:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0J22SdUz_FE&feature=player_detailpage#t=38s

Any suggestions? APIs I should look into? or sample source code for both the phone and tablet? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The ACR 122 driver downloads have an Android example app. The app is crude, but allows for sending low-level messages to the reader. You can use a library like [nfctools](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools) to go from high-level NDEF messages to low-level read/write commands. See also [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/nfc-developers/acr122/nfc-developers/6L5PIwTzGHQ/xKUW3yfZ-_EJ).

Note that if battery level drops below the ACR 122's power requirement, you'll see a disconnect event right after the connect event.